# Excel Forecast with occasional random numbers [Capacity Planning]

Tags: excel, server, forecasting, capacity-planning

I'm currently working on a capacity plan and forecasting for future growth. As we get larger and acquire more customers, we'll eventually stall out and our numbers will start to slow. I'd like to figure a way to add random numbers into my forecast, that'll show a "decrease"

Example:

2008: 20
2009: 32
2010: 45
2011: 49
2012: 52
2013: 60
2014: 72
2015: 88
2016: 102
2017: 113
2018: 142
2019: 130
2020: 127

etc, etc - hope this all makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Statistical software like R would me much more suited for this.  Ideally, as a business, you will continue acquiring more customers at a steady rate, but the *relative* percentages of customer acquisitions will level off.

I will explain the Excel I made for you.  For the years 2008-2017, we have data which you gave me.  I use that data to calculate the 2-year moving average and 2-year moving standard deviation over and over again.  These values are not all that useful, except for in the calculation of the random numbers we are looking for.

In 2018, we generate random numbers on a Gaussian distribution using the past-2-year moving average and past-2-year standard deviation. This generates *completely random* numbers, and generally come out to be somewhat interesting.  These numbers are recalculated every time you edit a formula, which is neat (double click any cell, press enter, watch the numbers move).  I also included a graph of the expected growth over time.  It is a fun tool to play with, if I do say so myself.  I included a screenshot here:

[image: Screenshot of Template]

For those of you who like statistics, the function I used was `=NORMINV(RAND(),mean,stddev)`.  This creates a Gaussian distribution around some mean value and stddev.  It is quite interesting, and has the nice effect of "leveling off" most of the time in calculations, which is perfect for this application.

The only problem is, I have no idea how to get this small file to you.  **Someone please comment back to let me know how so I can help this poor soul out.**

Comment: Sure, that is fine, if you are able to include that in comments.

Comment: taco@outlook.com

Comment: were you able to get it? i could really use that sheet tonight - if not, no worries.

Comment: It has been sent.  I would recommend also doing a similar analysis but instead of analyzing the "total customers" number, do the calculations based on the growth %.  This way, you will trend toward a steady growth rate in the future.

Comment: " Someone please comment back to let me know how so I can help this poor soul out." <-- this really make my day...  glad it solved. [ :